# How to force Chrome to open correct link

Tags: html, google-chrome

Google Chrome opens invalid links on click.

To reproduce, open page

in Chrome and move mouse cursor to text

In page source this link is defined as

```
<a class="fn" href="/store/Store/Details?product=CPU-EP0520EL01"
                        rel="product">
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a>
```

And thus should open link `/store/Store/Details?product=CPU-EP0520EL01`

Chrome shows wrong link  `/store/Store/Details?product=C225E` in bottom and opens also this wrong page.

How to fix this ?
Internet Explorer 9 opens correct page.

Comment: According to Chrome's developer tool, the div with class blueBoxImgMask takes up the *entire* page. It's inside the link to the C225E product, and that's why clicking anywhere on the page leads to that address. If you scroll down, that div isn't in the way anymore, which is why later links on the page work; they're not blocked by the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have some invalid html. If you click anywhere on the page, it opens up to /store/Store/Details?product=C225E.

Try starting at lines 206:
`<a href="/store/ShoppingCart?Length=12" id="cart-status" style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:-5px;color:blue">(0)</a>
</a>`

the page doesn't render properly in FF as well.

-----------------EDIT/UPDATE----------------

[image: Example of invalid html]

As you can see, i'm above the content and my cursor is not any a link, but if you look on the bottom of the page, I am noticing that it's linking to the invalid url. Only till after your fourth product item do I notice this behavior disappear.

Check line 206 for the invalid html and see if it's not an open link tag, as previously suggested that is causing you this issue.

Comment: I product names below are clicked, Chrome also opens correct page. Invalid links are opened for first products in page. I dont understand answer, what to start? Chrome console does not show any error on load, how to find what is wrong?